# convert to application.worksheetfunction.sumproduct

Tags: excel, vb6, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

can someone convert this formula SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>B:B))?

A:A and B:B are worksheet

this must count the number of cells less than in column b

application.worksheetfunction.sumproduct

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Evaluate()**

```
Sub lexation()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>B:B))")
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: the answer must be number not true or false